# Умные переходы по презентации PowerPoint 2013

Tags: office, powerpoint, onlyoffice

Нужно сделать умные переходы, или как еще называется такая фигня, между слайдами на презентации. Как это должно приблизительно выглядеть: есть на слайде большая карта мира с разными странами, и нужно что бы при нажатии на отдельную страну у нас выводилась инфа по ней, я если честно вообще не представляю как это сделать в PowerPoint. Буду благодарен за любые советы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче для умной карты есть дополнение в PowerPoint ArcGIS Maps. Больше информации есть по ссылке: https://doc.arcgis.com/ru/maps-for-office/design-and-use/add-a-map-to-powerpoint.htm